# Polymer 1.0 dom-if vs hidden

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

From https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/dom-if

> When if becomes falsey, the stamped content is hidden but not removed from dom. When if subsequently becomes truthy again, the content is simply re-shown. This approach is used due to its favorable performance characteristics: the expense of creating template content is paid only once and lazily.

I thought this was the behavior of `hidden` attribute, thus `hidden` being cheaper than `dom-if` since the template would not get restamped with `hidden`. Since 'no restamp' is the default behavior `dom-if`, what is the difference between `dom-if` and `hidden` and how is `hidden` better for performance? Polymer best practices notes that `hidden` is cheaper.

Comment: This question is still relevant with Polymer 2.x

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My understanding of it is that `dom-if` does not stamp *until* the expression becomes truthy, but after doing so it behaves much like `[hidden]` does. In that way `dom-if` is a pessimistic `[hidden]` that defers stamping for as long as possible.

This lazy-loading approach is favorable in certain situations where stamping the template would be very resource intensive. For example if the template was very large with multiple custom components that have to be initialized. If you had just used the `hidden` attribute there you would pay the performance cost of creating all of that DOM only for it to not be visible until later.

For simple cases, such as hiding or showing some text, a div or two, etc. the `hidden` attribute may be faster because the cost of creating those elements and then hiding them may be less than creating a `<template>` instance to hold your code, Polymer setting up listeners to monitor the expression for truthiness, then, when it becomes truthy, all the overhead for stamping the template, parsing it for binding expressions, etc. This is particularly true for the browsers where `<template>` support is polyfilled.

Thinking it through for your situation (and ideally testing it) is the best route to take. Often times the differences may be negligible but do take special care if this part of your code happens to be in a `dom-repeat` with a lot of items or anything that happens frequently. The difference could add up.

Comment: I recently looked into the performance of `hidden` vs `dom-if`, and the very, very general conclusion I came to was that if the content being hidden contains Polymer components, `dom-if` is probably faster; if it's just native HTML elements, `hidden` was faster.

Answer (score 3):

Hidden interferes with the `display` CSS property and therefore `dom-if` is a better option.

If you have

```
:host {display: block;}
```

setting `hidden` on the components host element won't hide it.
You would also need to add a global style like

```
[hidden] { display: none !important;}
```

to make it work reliably (and to make it work in IE9 which doesn't support `hidden` AFAIR).